# After update UWSim only with --disableShaders

Tags: ros, rosrun, uwsim, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Groovy and UWSim and everything was working fine.
Next day Ubuntu "Update Manager" said there is cca 100 updates recommended and I updated everything. After that I can run UWSim only with

```
rosrun UWSim UWSim --disableShaders
```

What I need to do to repair that so I can run UWSim normally?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59933/after-update-uwsim-only-with---disableshaders/) by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

UWSim has some pending issues with ocean shaders on some graphic cards from osgOcean visual effects but if it worked earlier it should work. You should check your graphics card configuration. If you are running UWSim on a laptop make sure you are running dedicated graphics card instead of proccesor for UWSim (common error). Some modern nvidia cards on laptops require a bumblebee installation and run UWSim with optirun.

Anyway shaders are a graphic issue so if it was working before the update problem must be on graphic configuration.

Besides that are you using Groovy?, as far as I know latest versions of UWSim do not support Groovy provided that osgWorks version used in UWSim is not working on it. Did you fixed that? or are you using an earlier version?. Just wondering...

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on 2013-04-04**:
I`m not using laptop, my graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series it should work. I run latest version of UWSim on ubuntu on virtual machine... Did not know that that do not support groovy. But it word earlier? What should i do?

**Comment by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on 2013-04-04**:
what i run UWSim it says: [ INFO] [1365152628.435978708]: pluginlib WARNING: PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS is deprecated, please use PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS instead. You can run the script 'plugin_macro_update' provided with pluginlib in your package source folder to automatically and recursively update le

**Comment by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on 2013-04-04**:
legacy macros

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2013-04-05**:
So it should be something about drivers. Do you know if any of that updates were related to graphic drivers?. I would go for checking 3d acceleration and graphic drivers something may have broken.